# Scheduling Azure Machine Learning Experimnets

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

How do i schedule Azure ML Experiments which is not deployed as web service?

I have developed a Azure Experiment which imports data from on-premise database and exports data to SQL db. How can i schedule that to run weekly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Azure PowerShell** for automating this task, and use **Windows Task Scheduler** to schedule this script to run automatically.

For Azure PowerShell,

You may visit [**this page**](https://github.com/hning86/azuremlps) to setup an Azure PowerShell script. It's a long journey, but it's worth it. Make sure to ***follow the prerequisites to be installed on your local PC (Azure-PowerShell v4.0.1)***.

For Windows Task Scheduler,

Visit [**this link**](https://www.metalogix.com/help/Content%20Matrix%20Console/SharePoint%20Edition/002_HowTo/004_SharePointActions/012_SchedulingPowerShell.htm) to schedule your created Azure PowerShell script to run at a scheduled/repeated time.